# Definition of coroots

Tags: representation-theory, root-systems

I'm having a bit of trouble with the definition of coroots.

From textbooks, we know that given a root system $\Phi$ with $\alpha \in \Phi$, there exists a coroot system $\Phi^{\vee}$ with $\alpha^{\vee} \in \Phi^{\vee}$ such that $\alpha^{\vee} = \frac{2 \alpha}{\alpha^2}$. But $\Phi$ consists of elements of $\mathfrak{g_0^*}$ whilst $\Phi$ consists of elements of $\mathfrak{g_0}$. 
Therefore I don't understand how $\alpha^{\vee}$ can be defined as such, given this would make it an element of $\mathfrak{g_0^*}$.

Given the standard isomorphism $\mathfrak{i}:\mathfrak{g_0} \to \mathfrak{g_0^*}$, shouldn't we take $\alpha^{\vee} = \frac{2 \mathfrak{i^{-1}}(\alpha)}{\alpha^2}$ instead?

Comment: The definition of $\alpha^{\vee}$ is $\frac{(\alpha,\cdot)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$.

Comment: To spell out what Math.StackExchange has said, there is a natural isomorphism $\mathfrak{g}_0\cong\mathfrak{g}_0^{**}$ and $\alpha^{\vee}\in\mathfrak{g}_0^{**}$ is defined by $\alpha^{\vee}(\beta)=\frac{2(\alpha,\beta)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$.